# Footnote number didn't show correctly

Tags: footnotes

Here is a least workable sample for the issue I met:

If I am using below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=70mm,paperheight=100mm,margin=1mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

% \usepackage{pifont}
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand*{\circnum}[1]{%
%   \expandafter\@circnum\csname c@#1\endcsname
% }
% \newcommand*{\@circnum}[1]{%
%   \ifnum#1<1 %
%   \@ctrerr
%   \else
%   \ifnum#1>20 %
%   \@ctrerr
%   \else
%   \ding{\numexpr 181+(#1)\relax}%
%   \fi
%   \fi
% }
% \makeatother

% \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\circnum{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}m{2em}|>{\centering}m{2em}|>{\centering}m{8.3em}|}
  \toprule
  A & B & C \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  A & B & \begin{enumerate}
    \tiny
  \item ASD\footnote{first}
  \item ASD\footnote{second}
  \end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I can get good results, but if I uncomment the code above, as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=70mm,paperheight=100mm,margin=1mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\circnum}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@circnum\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\newcommand*{\@circnum}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1 %
  \@ctrerr
  \else
  \ifnum#1>20 %
  \@ctrerr
  \else
  \ding{\numexpr 181+(#1)\relax}%
  \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\circnum{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}m{2em}|>{\centering}m{2em}|>{\centering}m{8.3em}|}
  \toprule
  A & B & C \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  A & B & \begin{enumerate}
    \tiny
  \item ASD\footnote{first}
  \item ASD\footnote{second}
  \end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I will get same footnote number in the bottom as this picture:

[image]

Please kindly help on this. I am using TexLive2018 full schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `\the`:

```
\newcommand*{\@circnum}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<1
    \@ctrerr
  \else
    \ifnum#1>20
      \@ctrerr
    \else
      \ding{\the\numexpr 181+(#1)\relax}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

This will expand to the value at the moment the macro is called.

[image]